# How to add if condition inside this helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am not able to give the if condition inside this method.

```
def published_comment
            "<li>
              <div id='comment_#{@comment.anchor}' class='comment #{@comment.state}' data-comment-id='#{@comment.to_param}'>
                <div>
                  #{ avatar }
                  #{ userbar }
                  <div class='cbody'>#{ @comment.content }</div>
                  #{ reply }

                  #{ if controller.try(:current_user).try(:admin?) }
                    #{ approved_comment } 
                  #{ end } 

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class='form_holder'></div>
              #{ children }
            </li>"
          end
```

Comment: What should your if condition do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a html string separately:

```
def published_comment
  html = "<li>
    <div id='comment_#{@comment.anchor}' class='comment #{@comment.state}' data-comment-id='#{@comment.to_param}'>
      <div>
        #{ avatar }
        #{ userbar }
        <div class='cbody'>#{ @comment.content }</div>
        #{ reply }
  "

  html <<  approved_comment if  controller.try(:current_user).try(:admin?)


  html <<  "</div>
    </div>
    <div class='form_holder'></div>
    #{ children }
  </li>"

  html
end
```

But better move this html to a partial and call it from a helper if you need.

```
def published_comment(comment)
  render 'published_comment', locals: { comment: comment }
end
```